# Multithreading a singlethreading class

Tags: multithreading

Currently my java method runs for about 200 different datasets sequentially and make entries in db for each dataset. Now I want to make this using multithread. Which approach should I take?

Comment: What do you man by **which approach**? What approaches you thought out so far? Currently, why are you doing sequentially ? What are you trying to achieve by multi thread? What is your data set ? How big & independent are you data sets? Which technology you currently use to insert?

Comment: I wanted to use executer java implementation. we are calling out X number of procedures internally. Currently if we have 500 data sets we will call procedures 500*X times and populated some table. Now I wanted to do this using multithreading to improve performance

Comment: so what challenges you face? SO is not a place to ask for approach, here you ask if you started something & are stuck. Approach suggestion is obviously too broad.

Comment: I am stuck finalizing the approach if I have a single db connection which is shared across multiple threads. Will this help or we should have different connection for different threads?

Comment: You will need multiple connections working out of a connection pool.

Comment: What if I have single connection shared among threads. Will it not improve the performance?

Comment: To give you a better idea, you need to add some code to question that you are trying to multi thread. I have not seen a multi threaded application working on a single db connection. Also, why are you constrained to a single connection?

Comment: multithreading with single connection can improve  the performance, if threads spend some significant time preparing data, and only then block connection to sent them to DB.